# In blade template how to insert variable inside double curly braces

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

im new to laravel and i dont know how to do this.

i want to insert this @{{comment.user.avatar}}

inside this `<img src={{ asset("images/profile/{comment.user.avatar}") }} />`

what im getting is this

```
<img src="http://localhost:89/images/profile/{comment.user.avatar}">
```

what i want is

```
<img src="http://localhost:89/images/profile/avatarpicture.jpg">
```

this is my complete code

```
<div class="card" v-for="comment in comments">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <img src={{ asset("images/profile/") }}@{{comment.user.avatar}} style='height:50px; width:50px' /> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-content">   
                                    <p class="subtitle is-6">@{{comment.user.firstname}} said...</p>
                                    <p>
                                        @{{comment.body}}
                                    </p>
                                    <span style="color: #aaa;" class="is-size-7">on @{{comment.created_at}}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and this is my javascript

```
@section('scripts')
    <script>
      const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          comments: {},
          commentBox: '',
          post: {!! $post->toJson() !!},
          user: {!! Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->toJson() : 'null' !!}
        },
        mounted(){
          this.getComments();
        //   this.listen();
        },
        methods:{
          getComments(){
            axios.get(`/api/posts/${this.post.id}/comments`)
              .then((response) => {
                this.comments = response.data
              })
              .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
              })
          },


        }
      });

    </script>
```

thank you in advance

arnel

Comment: what is a `comment.user.avata`r ??

Comment: {{ asset("images/profile/") }}{{comment.user.avatar}} use this add one beside the other make sure to put **$** in case needed like {{ $comment.user.avatar }}

Comment: comment is object or route name??

Comment: The way you try to get image is JavaScript (vue.js) in blade you should get it like `{{$comment->user->avatar}}`

Comment: the comment part is looping in  v-for="comment in comments" using vue.js.. and its displaying each record  like this @{{comment.body}} if i tyr using $comment->user->avatar its giving me this variable $comment not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue interpolation cannot be used inside HTML attributes.  You must bind an expression and wrap it in quotes.  Note `:src` is short hand for `v-bind:src`.

```
<img :src="'{{ asset("images/profile/") }}' + comment.user.avatar">
```

By doing this, you're binding the concatenated string:

```
'http://localhost:89/images/profile/' + comment.user.avatar
```